# VSTS deploy to third party hosting?

Tags: automation, html, azure

I'm using VSTS for some source control and was wodnering if it was possible to setup the build & deploy feature to deploy a basic html site to another hosting company other than azure.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hosting provider allows FTP access you could use the [FTP Upload](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/ftp-upload) step in your deployment pipeline.